# Find words between brackets - Regex + Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following words in a column in a table.

```
Deutsch (de)
English (en)
Português (pt)
Русский (ru)
한국어 (ko)
```

Please provide me a regex pattern that returns the last two characters within brackets. For example de for Deutsch (de), ru for Русский (ru) etc.,

Comment: `(..)` - too short to even be a comment!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\((\w{2})\)
```

Demo: http://rubular.com/r/ih4HxrjwiL

Now go learn some regex :-)

Answer (score 1):

Typically you delimit these symbols with a backslash: \ 

So if you want to look for a left bracket you put `\(` in its place in your regular expression.

Here's a reference on this and many similar Ruby regex topics: [ruby-doc's regex section](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/language.html#UL).

[Rubular.com](http://rubular.com/) is also a great tool for building and testing your Ruby regular expressions.